# MSAL js - acquireTokenSilent fails with X-Frame-Error

Tags: azure-ad-b2c, azure-ad-msal, react-aad-msal

We are using Azure AD B2C for React SPA web application and apis, we using b2c custom policy to support azure multi-tenant login, it's working ok for local accounts and google login, but when login with any azure account, getting iframe error from msal.js

**Site url**: https://app.skypointcloud.com

**Steps to reproduce**
- Login with any Azure account

**Error**

```
Refused to display 'https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/v2.0/authorize?client_id=b85d50b8-7e2f-xxxxx-xxxxx&redirect_uri=https%3a%2f%2fsicdpstage.b2clogin.com%2fsicdpstage.onmicrosoft.com%2foauth2%2fauthresp&response_type=code&scope=openid+profile&response_mode=form_post&nonce=xxxxxx&state=StateProperties%3xxxxx' in a frame because it set 'X-Frame-Options' to 'deny'.
```

Comment: If you open the link in a new tab, you’re probably being presented with an account selection screen?

Answer (score -1):

Currently this issued is caused by the B2C service, not the library. Can you try to invoke acquireTokenPopup or acquireTokenRedirect when this occurs.

Please refer the similar [issue](https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-authentication-library-for-js/issues/1437#issuecomment-624360526)

Comment: problem with acquireTokenPopup/acquireTokenRedirect is it will popup or redirect user to login flow again

Comment: acquireTokenPopup did work, but it gets blocked by browser